# Getting distance between two words in R

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a line in a file:

```
string <- "thanks so much for your help all along. i'll let you know when...."
```

I want to return a value indicating if the word `know` is within 6 words of `help`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a very crude implementation of Crayon's answer as a basic function:

```
withinRange <- function(string, term1, term2, threshold = 6) {
  x <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
  abs(grep(term1, x) - grep(term2, x)) <= threshold
}

withinRange(string, "help", "know")
# [1] TRUE

withinRange(string, "thanks", "know")
# [1] FALSE
```

---

I would suggest getting a basic idea of the text tools available to you, and using them to write such a function. Note Tyler's comment: As implemented, this can match multiple terms ("you" would match "you" and "your") leading to funny results. You'll need to determine how you want to deal with these cases to have a more useful function.

Comment: What about: `withinRange(string, "you", "know")`  Corner case but the poster may not even care.  Should `your` be counted?  +1

Comment: @TylerRinker, I was actually updating as you were posting your comment to highlight that this is just a starting point :-)

Comment: Thank you Ananda. It's exactly what I want!

Comment: +1 @AnandaMahto I woulda wrote an example too but I don't actually know `R` !

Answer (score 2):

you won't be able to get this from regex alone. I suggest splitting using space as delimiter, then loop or use a built-in function to do array search of your two terms and subtract the difference of the indexes (array positions).

**edit:** Okay I thought about it a second and perhaps this will work for you as a regex pattern:

`\bhelp(\s+[^\s]+){1,5}+\s+know\b`

This takes the same "space is the delimiter" concept. First matches for help then greedily up to 5 " word" then looks for " know" (since "know" would be the 6th).

Comment: I'm trying to convert your regex to something that R likes, but I don't quite follow it (partly because it's late where I am and I should actually probably call it a night). I'll look at it again in the morning :-)

Answer (score 0):

Split your string:

```
> words <- strsplit(string, '\\s')[[1]]
```

Build a indices vector:

```
> indices <- 1:length(words)
```

Name indices:

```
> names(indices) <- words
```

Compute distance between words:

```
> abs(indices["help"] - indices["know"]) < 6
FALSE
```

**EDIT** In a function

```
 distance <- function(string, term1, term2) {
    words <- strsplit(string, "\\s")[[1]]
    indices <- 1:length(words)
    names(indices) <- words
    abs(indices[term1] - indices[term2])
 }

 distance(string, "help", "know") < 6
```

**EDIT** Plus

There is a great advantage in indexing words, once its done you can work on a lot of statistics on a text.