# find word near another using stringr

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a simple problem, consider this example

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dataframe <- data_frame(mytext = c('stackoverflow is pretty good my friend',
                                   'but sometimes pretty bad as well'))

# A tibble: 2 x 1
                                  mytext
                                   <chr>
1 stackoverflow is pretty good my friend
2       but sometimes pretty bad as well
```

I want to count the number of times `stackoverflow` is near `good`. I use the following regex but it does not work.

```
dataframe %>%  mutate(mycount = str_count(mytext, 
 regex('stackoverflow(?:\\w+){0,5}good', ignore_case = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
                                  mytext mycount
                                   <chr>   <int>
1 stackoverflow is pretty good my friend       0
2       but sometimes pretty bad as well       0
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "*near*"?

Comment: here near is within 5 words. stackoverflow good would be OK, stackoverflow david arenburg is good good would be OK as well :D BUT good stackoverflow would be OK as well (not difficult, would just add | and reverse the correct pattern)

Comment: Looks like you are missing the spaces between words in your regex. How about `regex('stackoverflow (?:\\w+ ){0,5}good'` (note the spaces)

Comment: huuuuumm that is subtle. could you please elaborate a bit? I think your pattern would not match `stackoverflow good` dont you think?

Comment: Would that work? `sapply(strsplit(x, " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) diff(match(c("stackoverflow", "good"), x))) < 6`

Comment: thanks @DavidArenburg @MrFlick but I am trying to stick to `stringr` if possible

Comment: Related non-`stringr` answer: [Getting distance between two words in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316823/getting-distance-between-two-words-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it

```
dataframe %>%  
mutate(mycount = str_count(mytext, 
                 regex('stackoverflow\\W+(?:\\w+ ){0,5}good', ignore_case = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
                                  mytext mycount
                                   <chr>   <int>
1 stackoverflow is pretty good my friend       1
2       but sometimes pretty bad as well       0
3  stackoverflow good good stackoverflow       1
4                      stackoverflowgood       0
```

The key was adding the `\W+` meta-character that matches anything **between** words.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of trouble with this too and I'm still not sure why the things I was trying didn't work.  But I'm only decent at regular expressions, not an expert.  However, I was able to get it to work with lookback and lookforward.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dataframe <- data_frame(mytext = c('stackoverflow is pretty good my friend',
                                   'but sometimes pretty bad as well',
                                   'stackoverflow one two three four five six good',
                                   'stackoverflow good'))

dataframe
dataframe %>%  mutate(mycount = str_count(mytext, 
      regex('(?<=stackoverflow)\\s(?:\\w+\\s){0,5}(?=good)', ignore_case = TRUE)))
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#                                          mytext mycount
#                                           <chr>   <int>
#1         stackoverflow is pretty good my friend       1
#2               but sometimes pretty bad as well       0
#3 stackoverflow one two three four five six good       0
#4                             stackoverflow good       1
```

Answer (score 1):

The **corpus** library makes this pretty easy:

```
library(corpus)
dataframe <- data.frame(mytext = c('stackoverflow is pretty good my friend',
                                   'but sometimes pretty bad as well'))

# find instances of 'stackoverflow'
loc <- text_locate(dataframe$mytext, "stackoverflow")

# count the number of times 'good' is within 5 tokens
near_good <- (text_detect(text_sub(loc$before, -4, -1), "good")
              | text_detect(text_sub(loc$after, 1, 4), "good"))

# aggregate over text
count <- tapply(near_good, loc$text, sum, default = 0)
```

Conceptually, **corpus** treats text as a sequence of tokens. The library allows you to index these sequences using the `text_sub()` command. You can also change the definition of a token using a `text_filter()`.

Here's an example that works the same way but ignores punctuation-only tokens:

```
corpus <- corpus_frame(text = c("Stackoverflow, is pretty (?) GOOD my friend!",
                                "But sometimes pretty bad as well"))
text_filter(corpus)$drop_punct <- TRUE

loc <- text_locate(corpus, "stackoverflow")
near_good <- (text_detect(text_sub(loc$before, -4, -1), "good")
              | text_detect(text_sub(loc$after, 1, 4), "good"))
count <- tapply(near_good, loc$text, sum, default = 0)
```